# std::list<int> predicate call to function: Error C3867 function call missing argument list

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, predicate, c++98, stdlist

I am using std::list's predicate to update the list based on predicate. But calling in the OnInitDialog() throws compilation error. My code is as follows:

The below is .h:

```
class CDlgWindow : public CDialog
{
   private:
      bool single_digit (const int &value);
      int _days;
}
```

The below is .cpp:

```
    CDlgWindow::CDlgWindow(CWnd* pParent, CString strInfo, int days) //ctor
    { 
       _days = days;
      //_strInfo = strInfo
    }
    bool CDlgWindow::single_digit(const int& value)
    {
       return (value >= _days);
    }
    BOOL CDlgWindow::OnInitDialog()
    {
       CDialog::OnInitDialog();
       CenterWindow();
       .
       .
       .
       int numArr[] = {10,20,30,40};
       int size = sizeof(numArr)/sizeof(numArr[0]);
       std::list<int> numList (numArr, numArr+size);
       numList.remove_if(single_digit); //Error C3867 here!
       .
       .
    }
```

Complete error message:
`Error C3867 function call missing argument list, use '&CDlgWindow::single_digit' to create a pointer to member`.

I am trying to understand the functors concept. As I checked in C++11, we have lambdas for easier implementation. Please guide me to understand more on this issue. Thanks!

Comment: I suspect you may have left some important parts of the error message out, but you can't pass a member function for the predicate.

Comment: @RetiredNinja yes my bad! updated complete error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::list`'s [`remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove) member needs a unary predicate (`p`) that operates on values (`v`). The expression `p(v)` must be valid. Which it isn't if `p` is a non-static class member (see [repro](https://godbolt.org/z/b6MrhrnGe)).

There are two options:

1. Make the predicate (`single_digit`) a `static` class member:

   ```cpp
   class CDlgWindow : public CDialog
   {
      private:
         static bool single_digit (const int &value);
      // ...
   }
   ```
2. Make the predicate a free function:

   ```cpp
   bool single_digit(int const& value) {
       static int days_ = ...;
       return (value >= days_);
   }
   ```

If you go with option `1` you will have to make `_days` `static` as well, since a `static` member function cannot access non-static instance data. If `_days` is a compile-time constant, make sure to mark it `const` as well. That'll open up some compiler optimizations.

This is all hoping that things haven't significantly changed between C++98 and C++11. It's hard to find a C++98 compiler to verify this.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my code now, could you please check where these modifications needs to be done, I have done as per option 1 but getting Linker error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private:static int CDlgWindow::_days" (?_days@CDlgWindow...)

Comment: '_days' variable comes from another cpp file and pass it to this CDlgWindow ctor.

Comment: `static int _days;` at class scope only declares the variable. You also have to define it. To do so, you have to add the following to a single translation unit (usually the .cpp file with the `CDlgWindow` implementation): `int CDlgWindow::_days = 60;`. That will make the linker happy.

Comment: Yes but do I need to declare it in the ctor or anywhere outside? and I need to initialise this value in a ctor to pass it to OnInitDialog for populating the comboBox too. You can maybe update my code in the question itself.

Comment: You only have to add the `static` keyword to the `_days` declaration at class scope. The definition needs to be at global scope in the corresponding translation unit. You can keep the c'tor as is, but note that all dialogs of that class now share the same `_days` value.